# file_get_contents() returning raw data from url instead of json

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

This question have been asked many times before but none of the solution seems to works. I want to return JSON data from [this url](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=27.696694861033567,83.46625594498187&destinations=28.233514383842977,83.98651076641227&travelMode=driving&key=AikYJUU_G5X1EowlJ0vsa052KQ39WtEne9nI-dYjlH0xGNNIxCB83tdJC90Z9Pwp&distanceUnit=km) using `file_get_contents()` but it returning JSON data in raw format (*string*).

Here is my code:

```php
$data = file_get_contents('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=27.696694861033567,83.46625594498187&destinations=28.233514383842977,83.98651076641227&travelMode=driving&key=bingmaps_api_key&distanceUnit=km');
dd($data);
```

I have tried using curl but result is same it also return JSON data in raw format (*string*)

```php
$url = 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=27.696694861033567,83.46625594498187&destinations=28.233514383842977,83.98651076641227&travelMode=driving&key=ingmaps_api_key&distanceUnit=km';
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
    die('The cURL library is not installed.');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
dd($output);
```

Output I want
[image: Produced output]

Output it gives 
[image: Required output]

Comment: The question linked as dupicate is not what he was asking for I guess. You're rather looking for the `application/json` header. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script - also, you should remove your API keys.

Comment: `dd()` is Laravel's debug output function, right? Then yes, it'll just show the literal string as is. Usually you'd decode the JSON, and do something with it. If this script is just about playback, then an `echo` and the right MIME type would make your browser JSON prettifier engage (if this is what you want, then it's perhaps worth mentioning).

Comment: i will disable this key after a solution

Comment: when i do json_decode() it gives me error Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\json_decode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is nothing but a string. file_get_contents or cURL will always return string, you have to decode the string using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method which should give you the JSON object.

Comment: when i do json_decode() it gives me error Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\json_decode()

Comment: Looks like you don't have json extension enabled in your php configuration. you should install ext-json and enable it.